# How to display a Foreign Key in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My template is set up like this:

```
{% for deck in deck %}
<a href='{% url 'deck_detail' deck.title %}'>
<li class='deckCards'>
    <div class='deckText'>
    <div class='deckTitle'>{{deck.title}}</div>
    <div class='deckCreator'>{{deck.creator}}</div>
    <div class='deckSubject'>{{deck.subject}}</div>
    <div class='deckQuestion'>{{deck.questions.count}} Questions</div>
    <div class='deckAccuracy'>{{The part I need help with}}%<div>
    </div><!-- end of deckText -->
```

My model is like so:

```
class DeckAccuracy(models.Model):
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='accuracy')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='attempted_deck')
    deck_accuracy = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_of_attempts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.deck)
```

My view:

```
def DashboardView(request):
    user = request.user
    deck = Deck.objects.all()
    return render(request, "cards/dashboard.html", {'deck': deck,
        'user': user})
```

I can't figure out how to display the **deck accuracy** directly within the for loop of my template. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As you use a ForeignKey, there can be more than one deckaccuracy record to one deck. So you need to loop through the deck.accuracy.all array. So something like this should do it:

```
<div class='deckAccuracy'>{% for acc in deck.accuracy.al%} {{acc}} {% endfor %}<div>
```

If there is always only one deckaccuracy use a OneToOneField and then you can just use deck.accuracy to reference the value.